# Group by with paging (take skip)

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to make some kind of paging. But, I need to do it on a grouped result, because every time I do a page. It is a requirement that all data for a given group is fetched.

Below code:

```
var erere = dbCtx.StatusViewList
                 .GroupBy(p => p.TurbineNumber)
                 .OrderBy(p => p.FirstOrDefault().TurbineNumber)
                 .Skip(0)
                 .Take(10)
                 .ToList();
```

I have 200k items and the statement above seems to be so slow the connection times out. My best bet is its the orderby that slows it down. Any suggestions how to do this, or how to speed the statement above up?

Comment: Did you try `.OrderBy(g => g.Key))`? Also, you should probably use profiling to see what the generate SQL query looks like.

Comment: I think @MarcinJuraszek's advise will work in a perfect way. I analyzed the explain plan for the statement in the question and with the little change in the comment. Then I saw, there is 10 thousand times difference between costs of these queries.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but once it will be solved, you may try this optimization with EF skip and Take https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/12/06/skip-take-entity-framework-lambda.aspx

Comment: Have you checked your indexes? If you are going to group and sort by Turbine number you are going to want an index the query can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At your case, grouping on server side is not needed at all, because anyway you will get **all** data, but with additional overhead on server side. So try another approach:

```
var groupPage = dbCtx.StatusViewList.Select(x => TurbineNumber)
                  .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.TurbineNumber).Skip(40).Take(20).ToList();

var data = dbCtx.StatusViewList.Where(x => groupPage.Contains(x.TurbineNumber))
                  .ToList().GroupBy(x => x.TurbineNumber).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `GroupBy` needs to visit all elements to group all `StatusViews` into groups of `StatusViews` that have equal `TurbineNumber`.

After that, you take every group, from every group your take the first element and ask for its TurbineNumber, to sort by Turbine Number.

Apparently you take into account that a group of `StatusViews` might be empty (`FirstOrDefault`, instead of `First`), but then again, you assume that `FirstOrDefault` never returns null.

One of the things that could speed up your query is using the `Key` of your groups. The `Key` is the element on which you grouped, in your case the `TurbineNumber`: All elements in the a group have the same `TurbineNumber`.

```
var result = dbCtx.StatusViewList
    .GroupBy(statusView => statusView.TurbineNumber)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
    ...
```

I think that will be a first step to improve performance.

However, you return a fixed number of Groups. Some Groups might be huge, 1000s of elements, some groups might be small: only one element. So the result of one page could be 10 groups, each with 1000 elements, having a total of 10000 elements. It could also be 10 groups, each with 1 element, a total of 10 elements. I'm not sure if this would be the result you want by paging.

Wouldn't you prefer a page that always has the same number of elements, preferably with the same `TurbineNumber`, If there are not many same `TurbineNumbers` fill the rest of your page with the next `TurbineNumber`. If there are too many `StatusViews` with this `TurbineNumber` divide them into several pages?

Something like:

```
TurbineNumber StatusView
     4            A
     4            B
     4            F
     5            D
     5            K
     6            C
     6            Z
     6            Q
     6            W
     7            E
```

To do this, don't `GroupBy`, use `OrderBy` and then Skip and Take

```
IEnumerable<StatusView> GetPage(int pageNr, int pageSize)
{
     return dbCtx.StatusViewList
         .Orderby(statusView => statusView.TurbineNumber)
         .Skip(pageNr * pageSize)
         .Take(pageSize)
}
```

If you create an extra index for TurbineNumber, this will be very fast:

In your `DbContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`:

```
// Add an extra index on TurbineNumber:
var indexAttribute = new IndexAttribute("TurbineIndex", 0) {IsUnique = false}
var indexAnnotation =new IndexAnnotation(indexAttribute);
modelBuilder.Entity<Statusview>()
    .Property(statusView => statusView.TurbineNumber)
    .HasColumnAnnotation("MyIndexName", indexAnnotation);
```

Comment: But how do you make sure the Skip and Take ends at end of a group? It seems like 1 group is divided into multiple groups